# Prove that $X'=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So let's say that $Y'=X\setminus Y=X-Y$

Prove that $X'=\emptyset$

Any help on this one? Thanks!

Comment: So, $X'=X\setminus X$?

Comment: Can anything be in $X\setminus X$?

Comment: @d.k.o. that's what im thinking too, but i think that would be too easy XD. X is supposed to be another set which contains Y, so maybe it could be named differently other than X? Im pretty much lost on this one...

Comment: @CameronWilliams nope there cant be anything in X-X, so yeah it is ∅. But what if like the set was named B as opposed to X? Im pretty new to this so yeah..

Comment: Doesn't matter what the set is called. Any set $S$ satisfies $S\setminus S = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imagine that you are given some set $X$.

For an arbitrary set $Y$, you define
$$Y' = Y\setminus X$$
which is everything in $Y$ which is not in $X$.

In particular, I can use $Y=X$ in this definition, i.e. I use the definition on the set $X$ I was given.

This is
$$X' = X\setminus X = \emptyset,$$
since we remove all elements of $X$ from $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;Y'=X\setminus Y=X-Y\;.$

Prove that $\;X'=\emptyset\;.$

**Proof :**

By definition, $\;X’=X\setminus X\;.$

If there existed $\;x\in X’=X\setminus X\;,\;$ then $\;x\;$ would belong to $\;X\;$ and, at the same time, $\;x\;$ would not belong to $\;X\;,\;$ but it is absurd.

So it is imposible that there exists an element $\;x\;$ in $\;X’\;,\;$ hence $\;X’=\emptyset\;.$